# Build Pipeline Canceled - The pipeline is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to Queue an existing build that worked fine up until a few days ago. The message I am getting is the following:

> The pipeline is not valid. Job Phase_1: Step NuGetInstaller_1 input
>   externalEndpoints references service connection
>   {guid} which could not be found. The
>   service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use.
>   For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

From these links [Troubleshooting authorization for a YAML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=vsts#troubleshooting-authorization-for-a-yaml-pipeline)
 and [Build Error: The pipeline is not valid](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/290393/build-error-the-pipeline-is-not-valid.html) I understand that there is a chance that someone created a duplicate endpoint that prevents somehow the build ("***A duplicate endpoint (which points to a KeyVault) was created by someone not on our team and this duplicated endpoint was preventing any builds that referenced the endpoint.***") but I can't really find what exactly to look for and the suggestion of the first link didn't work.

Can anyone suggest what to look for or what might be the problem in my case?

Many thanks.

Comment: *The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use.* Have you validated that the service connection has not been deleted?

Comment: @DanielMann the thing is that I don't have any Service Connections set in the Pipeline. I haven't created the build either the Pipeline either the build and other builds work without a problem. In the tasks and the variables of the build I can't find any reference of a service connection and If I understand what I am reading correctly I don't have any task named "NuGetInstaller_1". Should I be looking somewhere else for this reference?